# How to use tensorflow model for predicting my own images

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've just started with tensorflow. I wrote a program that uses Fashion_MNIST dataset to train the model. And then predicts the labels using 'test_images'and it's working good so far. 
But what I am curious how can I use my own image of a shoe or shirt for prediction. Because all the test images are of shape 28*28. How can I do this ?

Comment: Easiest would be to down scale your images. You can use the python library PIL  for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you are engaged in is the task of data preparation and preprocessing. Among the things you must do already having a directory with images is the tagging of the images, for this task I recommend [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg).
If you also need the dimensionality of the input to be of a specific size like the example you give, you can use digital image processing software. The [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) library has dimensionality reduction tools that work for this.